# QGIS composer add attribute table with repeating columns

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas, composite, composer-manager

I need some help with QGIS print composer.  I use the atlas composer and I try to use `add attribute table` from layout tab.

I have create my expression where I want to print in composer.

field expression (that I want):

```
case when "myfield" is not null   then concat(myfield,' ',myfield1,' & ',myfield2) else concat(myfield1,' ',myfield3)
```

I have defined filter from `item properties` where I want to print with atlas:

```
intersects(buffer($geometry),50),$atlasgeometry)
```

but that shows like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6
value7
value8
value9
```

because of to many values I can't print them all in my layout.  I need a result like this:

```
value 1   value2
value 3   value4
value 5   value6
value 7   value8
value9
```

If the values are like this then I can print all.  If I want to add a legend then have option where you can choose columns

[image: columns]

That is what I need for my attributes but I can't find something like this.

Finally I try to create a new expression with my field and I try to add next feature but without success.

I tried this:

```
dbvaluebyid('test','f_field', @row_number ) ||'' ||dbvaluebyid('test','f_field', @row_number +1)
```

but from this expressions I don't take next feature.

and this:

```
case when "myfield" is not null   then concat(myfield,' ',myfield1,' & ',myfield2) else concat(myfield1,' ',myfield3)  end ||  '                                    ' || case when "myfield" is not null   then concat(myfield,' ',myfield1,' & ',myfield2) else concat(myfield1,' ',myfield3)
```

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried the mode "Repeat until finished" in Item Properties > "Frames" > "resize mode:"?

Comment: Have you tried creating a second attribute identical to the first, but filter the first attribute table to the first 5 records and the second attribute table to the last four records?

Comment: @KleberBarcelar that is not frame is attribute table I don't have option resize mode

Comment: @Knightshound I want to have double values export for per line that export is the result of filter

Comment: @KleberBarcelar `Repeat until finished ` show me new values in new empty page

Comment: do you know how many values it will be at max you want to display? If it is a resasonable amount, you coud add attribute fields and work with htnl labels (will add an answer if its case to elaborate it)

Comment: @ LaughU htnl labels ?html you mean ?the values is dynamic maybe for some feature is two minimum and maximum maybe 50,however can you show me an example with html ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, but it's not really interactive for the moment. However, it allows some nice tweaks to have a pretty table displayed  :

**In QGIS**

- Export your table in Excel

**In Excel or similar**

(Maybe this part could be automated in Excel)

- Filter the data if needed to have the table of your desire
- Create a new set of column after the first ones
- Cut and paste the extra records to the right of the first ones
- Get some style to your table

[image: Table transform]

**In Word or similar**

- Copy and paste your new table into a word document (check the display)
- Save as an html document if it's ok

[image: HTM word]

**Text Editor**

- Open the html file in a text editor (for example : Notepad ++)
- Copy the HTML code

**Back in QGIS**

- Create an HTML frame in your QGIS composer and paste the HTML code

[image: Last step in QGIS]

Now you have your data in 2 columns.. with style :)

Comment: I guess they must be better solution to try and keep the link with the original table and/or regenerate automatically the html. But it probably requires some coding to export directly the qgis table into an html code.